# Network connection breaks again and again?

Tags: networking, hardware-failure

My PC sometimes disconnects from the network. By disconnecting I mean without any possible reason. My system shows no error in network, no problem with the router and how do I know its only my PC problem because all other PC’s—laptops and smart devices—do not disconnect its only my PC.

And after sometimes the connection again gets complete, I also have to give my PC a static IP because it otherwise shows IP conflict error, I have reinstalled the OS several times but didn’t work then may be its hardware problem

And one thing is confusing that any download with torrent and any game server stays connected but things like opening a web page gets problem.

Also a couple of weaks ago I tinkered with the NIC card by enabling and disabling its promisc mode but i dont think its because of that or may be it is. So any suggestion.

I am using Windows XP SP3 and somtimes Windows 7. My machine is A Dell Pentium 4 Optiplex GX270 with 2GB ram, 3.2 ghz processor, BIOS version A07 and NIC is Intel(R)PRO/1000 MT Network connection.

Answer (score 0):

Goto Intel(R)PRO/1000 M's properties --> Power Management and make sure windows is not allowed to turn it off to save power.

[Screenshot](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/415447)

Comment: Yes i guess you are right the option was enabled but isn't this option default why would the company select this option i wonder.

Comment: It's used as power saving method on notebooks. IT is indeed illogical that it is active by default on desktop systems.